Двойной импорт из параллельных папок Python
Структура моего проекта:
|--MainFolder
|    |main.py
|    |file2.py
|--SubFolder
|    |main.py
|    |file2.py

Основной файл - MainFolder/main.py
из него я импортировал SubFolder/main.py используя sys
sys.path.append('/SubFolder/')
import main

В файле SubFolder/main.py есть импорт файла file2.py
import file2

планируется что будет импортироваться SubFolder/file2.py,
но у меня импортируется MainFolder/file2
Как сделать чтобы импортировалось из папки SubFolder?
Извиняюсь если вопрос глупый, но информации которая бы меня удовлетворяла не нашёл.

from SubFolder import file2
